# Clearing logcat on HTC one X

Tags: storage, insufficient-memory, htc-one-x, logging

I've faced with insufficient storage problem on my HTC One X (rooted, stock ROM 4.2.2, CWM recovery).
I've solve this problem before on a Samsung device by dialing *#9900# then press Delete dumpstate/logcat. However, I try that with HTC and it doesn't work. Anyone know how can I delete logcat or other method to fix this problem?

Updated : FYI, I have plenty of storage in  phone storage as well as in SDcard. I also try installing other app which seems to installed without problem. The app I'm having problem is Gallery Vault. Earlier, the app is installed and I uninstall it. Now I'm trying to reinstall it and I get insufficient storage error.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Clearing logcat can't make any difference to your storage problem. The logcat output is stored in a ring buffer, so it has a fixed size, and the ring buffer only exists on RAM: it isn't written to the storage at all.

See the frequent questions under the [insufficient-memory](/questions/tagged/insufficient-memory) tag for what to do when your phone storage is getting full.

Comment: I'm no Android guru, bur clearing the logcat/dumpstat on a Samsung Galaxy S2 solved exactly the same problem: apps could not be installed due to "no space" errors (even if gigabytes were free). After clearing it via the *#9900# menu, the problems were gone (also more than a gigabyte of storage was freed up).

PS: Is there a general "How to clear logcat/dumpstate?" question? Hopefully with an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I try deleting all file associate with the app (apk, settings, etc) I can now install the app. Seems like residue files are the culprit.